# Android Calendar

Tags: android, insert, calendar, exists

I am trying to put items into a calendar and can't really find out how to code it. This is what I have so far but it inserts it into the main calendar.

```
    String calName; 
    String calId = null;
    String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "name" };

    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, projection, null, null, null);
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

    event.put("calendar_id", calId);
    event.put("title", strTitle);
    event.put("description", strDescription);
    event.put("eventLocation", strLocation);
    event.put("dtstart", StartTime);
    event.put("dtend", EndTime);

    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    Uri calUri = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I create my own calendar to put events into
2. How do I insert my events into that calendar (using the code above or a new code)
3. How do I check to see if event already exists

~~~UPDATE:~~~

What I'm trying to do is my users will enter in an title and a date and my app will take that title and date, put them into a database (so far all that I have done) and now I want to take the title and date and put them into a special calendar devoted for just my apps events. First thing I need to do is have the app create a new calendar. Than insert events into that calendar which the code below helps me do kind of. Still playing with it. Than I want to rerun my app and check to see if the event exists. Thats all.

Comment: Please help to answer this thread also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658179/android-calendar-show-continuous-event-that-extends-for-2-or-more-days

Answer (score 2):

First of all the content resolver changes since 2.2 I think from `content://calendar/calendars` to `content://com.android.calendar/calendars`.

To insert Event , retrieve Event check this code

https://github.com/Rabgs/AndroidLib_Google-Calendar/blob/master/src/net/mobiwide/agenda/google/GoogleAgenda.java

You will find everything you need and how to handle the content resolver change across platforms .

Comment: The link is dead and I couldn't find where it moved to, if it did.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could do this in a couple different ways, but the best way I would recommend is using a [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) for storing your calendar events.
2. You will use standard SQL [insert statements](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) to add your events to your calendar database.
3. You will use standard [select (query) statements](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to retrieve your events.

Comment: I already have them in a database. I'm trying to send them over to the calendar so they sync to my gmail account so I can see them online as well as have them go off in the calendar to remind me of them.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to reflect this.  I will have to think some more about it before I can give a better answer.  You should consider updating your question to ask what you really want to be answered.

Comment: Updated. Tell me if you need any more info

Answer (score 0):

To update Google Calendar, use the [Google Calendar GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).

Comment: I like the link but I can't really figure it out. I've tried copying over the source code and the jar files but everytime I run it it gives me a force close. Is there a simple way to just send it to the phone calendar and not to the online google calendar?